# 7Zip wrapper without 7za.dll

Tags: c++, 7zip, compression

I need to use 7zip in my application and I am looking for a wrapper over the LZMA sdk.
I found an interesting one SevenZip++ (https://bitbucket.org/cmcnab/sevenzip/overview) developed by Chadwick McNab.
The problem is that this wrapper uses 7za.dll.

Is it possible to use 7zip in an application without 7za.dll?
There is any wrapper for LZMA sdk that doesn't use 7za.dll?

Comment: Why do you need a wrapper?

Comment: I would like a solution that doesn't use the 7za.dll. Also calling with parameters 7zr.exe it's not a good solution for me.
I would like code that I could compile myself and not use 3Party dlls.

Comment: Yes, but why do you need a wrapper. You've got the source code to LZMA. Use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is really possible. I once integrated 7-zip sources into the project as a whole, and then used command line interface to the functionality. They are well written in the sense that you do not need to change the library - just include all files in your project and build as a single executable. You also gain Linux version for free the same time.

This approach will be faster than extract LZMA library (it is really a C library) from 7-zip sources and use its underlying C-interface.

Comment: You integrated into your project the 7zr.exe and you called it with command parameters?